Why is this `NaN` happening when using the result of a fraction but not hard typing the number?
I found a weird behaviour of R that I can't understand. The below operation returns NaN but if you hardcode the result of the fraction then returns the value. Can anyone give me a clue about why is this happening?
x <- -0.24
(x/5)^(1.5)
#> [1] NaN

y <- x/5
y^1.5
#> [1] NaN

x/5
#> [1] -0.048
-0.048^1.5
#> [1] -0.01051627

Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.1.0

Because -0.048^1.5 is -(0.048^1.5), not (-0.048)^1.5. In other words, when you’re using a variable you are actually calculating a different value, using different operations.

Does this answer your question? Strange behavior of R - as a comment to that question points out, this is in the R FAQ

Yes, this answer my question. However, I rather not to delete the question as it can help others to find this. I couldn't find the previous question because the title was too generic.
